# How to display the number of people who line in same area and with same characteristics

Tags: sql, count, left-join, where-clause

I m new to sql, so i ask for help is that possible to display the number of people who live in same area with same characteristics.
Here is my sample table.

area

```
AreaID  Area_name
-----------------
001     India 
002     Boston
003     US
```

Second table :

Person

```
P_Id  | P_name |  car  | AreaID
------|--------|-------|-------
P01   | John   |  yes  | 001
P02   | Mary   |  null | 001
P03   | Chris  |  yes  | 003
P04   | Jane   |  null | 001
P05   | Ben    |  null | 002
...   
... 
P99   | May    |  null | 002
...
```

i would like have a query to return number of people which registered in the table.

The answer i hope would be show the count of people have car in same area.

```
AreaID | Havecar
-------|--------
001    |       2
002    |       7
```

Or show the most number of people have car from different

```
AreaID  | numberOfPeople
--------|--------------
002     |         32
```

are this two possible be make using sql query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The answer I hope woule be show the count of people have car in same area.

You can use aggregation:

```
select areaid, count(*) havecar
from person
where car = 'yes'
group by areaid
```

If you also want to show areas without any car, then you can start from the `area` table, and bring `person` with a `left join`:

```
select a.areaid, coalesce(p.havecar, 0) havecar
from area
left join (
    select areaid, count(*) havecar
    from person
    where car = 'yes'
    group by areaid
) p on p.areaid = a.areaid
```

Comment: thanks for answering my question. Want to ask, if the car attribute is inserted like  BMW and Jaguar instead of yes and null is still remaining. I already change the where car ='Jaguar' but why it show no row selected

Comment: @user12717227: you would change the `where` clause to `where car is not null`.

Comment: thanks, @GMB, till now i just know can just type <code>is not null</code>.Learn a new thing.

Answer (score 1):

Use a GROUP BY query:

```
SELECT AREAID, CAR, COUNT(*) AS HAVECAR
  FROM PERSON
  GROUP BY AREAID, CAR
  HAVING CAR = 'yes'
  ORDER BY AREAID, CAR
```

[db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f91cb0726845870f691fe7a8a288f1b0)